# How can I count two diffferent occurences in a dataframe in one pass?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+---------+------+
|  Col1   | Col2 |
+---------+------+
| Value 1 | A    |
| Value 2 | D    |
| Value 3 | B    |
| Value 4 | C    |
| Value 5 | A    |
| Value 6 | B    |
+---------+------+
```

I need to count the number of times `A` appears and also the number of times `B` appears. Currently I am just doing:

```
val aCount = dataframe.where("Col2 = A").count()
val bCount = dataframe.where("Col2 = B").count()
```

But this is causing the whole DAG to execute twice, once for each count. The data I am working with is massive so I can't just cache `dataframe` and doing this twice is taking too long.
Is there a way I can do both counts in one pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this on 1 pass:

```
val countMap = dataframe
  .where($"Col2".isin("A","B"))
  .groupBy($"Col2")
  .count()
  .as[(String,Long)].collect()
  .toMap

val aCount = countMap("A")
val bCount = countMap("B")
```

or with only 1 statement:

```
val Array(aCount,bCount) = dataframe
  .where($"Col2".isin("A","B"))
  .groupBy($"Col2")
  .count()
  .orderBy($"Col2")
  .select($"count").as[Long]
  .collect()
```

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
val data = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  ("Value 1", "A"), 
  ("Value 2", "D"),
  ("Value 3", "B"),
  ("Value 4", "C"), 
  ("Value 5", "A"), 
  ("Value 6", "B"))
).toDF("Col1", "Col2")
```

Is this what you are looking for?

```
data.filter($"Col2".isin("A", "B")).groupBy("Col2").count.show
+----+-----+
|Col2|count|
+----+-----+
|   B|    2|
|   A|    2|
+----+-----+
```

You could then potentially `.collect` and extract the key/value pairs